# How can I protect the amplifier behind a headphone jack when interfacing with external circuitry?

Tags: audio, amplifier, fuses

I am wanting to mess with the output of my guitar amp. Not actually opening it up, just taking the headphone-output and connecting it to a breadboard and such.

What form of protection, if any, should I use to keep from frying my amplifier (which cost $100) in the case of a short or other problem.

Are most amplifiers self-protecting? I'm unsure on how most commercial audio amplifiers work.

Note: My guitar amp is a 60W amplifier, but I of course won't be using it at full power

Comment: @reem, well I didn't mean fuse then. I disagree that this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @reemrevnivek, Close Votes go away with time. If the "issue" that causes a close vote resolves then no one else will vote and it will resolve itself.

Comment: I made some minor edits to remove the reference to fuses, which was already covered in a different question (and is inappropriate in this case).  I had previously voted to close as a duplicate do to these references, but I think it can now stay open.  If the close vote is still there when you read this, just give it a few days, and, as Kortuk said, it will disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headphone output is almost certainly protected with output resistors.  It will be extremely hard to damage it by a typical breadboard circuit.

Nevertheless, if you would like more protection, put a 1k resistor in series with the signal at the headphone plug.   Now damage is almost impossible.

Comment: @earlz, power dissipated is Voltage times Current. This means that a 1k resistor will reduce your possible output current to be very small, this resistor is a "power limiting" resistor as markrages notes.